# RegEx.Replace is only replacing first occurrence, need all

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having an issue with `Regex.Replace` in C# as it doesn't seem to be replacing all occurrences of the matched pattern.

```
private string ReplaceBBCode(string inStr)  
{  
    var outStr = Regex.Replace(inStr, @"\[(b|i|u)\](.*?)\[/\1\]", @"<$1>$2</$1>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);  
    outStr = Regex.Replace(outStr, "(\r|\n)+", "<br />"); 
    return outStr; 
}
```

The input string:

```
[b]Saint Paul's Food Kitchen[/b]    [b]  [/b]Saint Paul's food kitchen opens weekly to provide food to those in need.
```

The result:

```
<b>Saint Paul's Food Kitchen</b>    [b]  [/b]Saint Paul's food kitchen opens weekly to provide food to those in need.
```

I've tested this in `regexhero.net` and it works exactly as it should there.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, copied the wrong version of the function. It now shows the correct code, that behaves incorrectly for me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the link. I figured since it was specific to the .NET implementation of regular expressions it should be in there, but I understand and will keep this in mind.

Comment: Even granted it's specific to .NET, it still has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: that's not the result I'm getting.  I'm getting a completely different result when i copy and  paste your code

Comment: Yeah. What Sam I am said. I get "<\1>\2</\1>Saint Paul's food kitchen opens weekly to provide food to those in need." out of your regex so your problem isn't just to do with all occurrences... Does the same in regexhero as well...

Comment: Also the answer give by Ahmed KRAIEM and then deleted does have a valid point that Regex are probably not needed and using Replace would do just as well. Depends what you want to do about improperly matched tags and such like though.

Comment: @Chris corrected and undeleted :)

Comment: @Derokorian: The new function after the edit works fine for me and outputs `<b>Saint Paul's Food Kitchen</b>    <b>  </b>Saint Paul's food kitchen opens weekly to provide food to those in need.` Can you confirm that you really are using that function and that these really are the results you are seeing?

Comment: Note that nested tags are not handled by this method `[b]foo[i]bar[/i]foo[/b]` won't work as expected.

Comment: I've found a solution that it won't let me post yet because I have no reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the issue, it also handles nested tags. Not sure why, but rebuilding over and over it still was causing errors. Its possible our VS2010 is corrupted and not building properly, or that the framework is corrupted. Not sure what the cause of the problem is, but this solved it:

```
private string ReplaceBBCode(string inStr)
{
    var outStr = inStr;
    var bbre = new Regex(@"\[(b|i|u)\](.*?)\[/\1\]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    while( bbre.IsMatch(outStr))
        outStr = bbre.Replace(outStr, @"<$1>$2</$1>");
    outStr = Regex.Replace(outStr, "(\r|\n)+", "<br />");
    return outStr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The output I'm getting is completely different from what you say you're getting, but

The biggest problem I see, is that you probably don't want your regex to be greedy.

try replacing the `.*` with `.*?`

Comment: Yeah, despite the problem with the question this is possibly the answer. However the fact that the output the OP has includes the second `[b] [/b]` suggests that it isn't greedy. However, without the actual regex used it is impossible to say if the given output is actually genuine or not.

Answer (score 1):

No need for Regex:

```
private static string ReplaceBBCode(string inStr)  
{  
    return inStr.Replace("[b]", "<b>").Replace("[/b]", "</b>")
                .Replace("[i]", "<i>").Replace("[/i]", "</i>")
                .Replace("[u]", "<u>").Replace("[/u]", "</u>")
                .Replace("\r\n", "\n")
                .Replace("\n", "<br />"); 
}
```

I like this one better:

```
private static string ReplaceBBCode(string inStr)  
{
    StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder();
    bool addBR = false;
    for(int i=0; i<inStr.Length; i++){
        if (addBR){
            outStr.Append("<br />");
            addBR = false;
        }
        if (inStr[i] == '\r' || inStr[i] == '\n'){
            if (!addBR)
                addBR = true;
        }
        else {
            addBR = false;
            if (i+2 < inStr.Length && inStr[i] == '[' 
                && (inStr[i+1] == 'b' ||  inStr[i+1] == 'i' ||  inStr[i+1] == 'u')
                && inStr[i+2] == ']'){
                outStr.Append("<").Append(inStr[i+1]).Append(">");
                i+=2;
            }
            else if(i+3 < inStr.Length && inStr[i] == '[' && inStr[i+1] == '/'
                && (inStr[i+2] == 'b' ||  inStr[i+2] == 'i' ||  inStr[i+2] == 'u')
                && inStr[i+3] == ']'){
                outStr.Append("</").Append(inStr[i+2]).Append(">");
                i+=3;
            }
            else
                outStr.Append(inStr[i]);
        }
    }
    return outStr.ToString();
}
```

Comment: And what happens if they have unbalanced tags in the input? Regex allows making sure they are always properly balanced.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment. What happens is pretty obvious. :)